# why i get Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error , Anyone knows this answer

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Punjab</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CV2.css">
    <script src="./keyin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="side-bar">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./cv2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
table += "</table>";

document.querySelector("side-bar").innerHTML =  table ;
```

Comment: side-bar is a class so change the selector in query-selector to ".side-bar" (include the dot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using `querySelector` use dot while using class selector

```
document.querySelector('.side-bar').innerHTML = "your value"
```